# Split command in C++20

Tags: c++, performance, c++20

The Windows OS doesn't feature a `Split` command and although I do have a Linux partition, I mainly use Windows 11. As such, I implemented the `Split` command in C++20 so that I can use it on Windows.

The program seems pretty fast; I used it with a large Linux ISO(~4GB) and it took only few seconds to finish(<10s). Please review it and tell me if there is room for some performance gains:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <filesystem>

#define defaultChunkSize 500'000'000UL;

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

void splitFile(const std::string& source, const std::string& outputPrefix, unsigned long chunkSize) {
    std::ifstream inputFile(source, std::ios::binary);
    if (!inputFile) {
        std::cerr << "Error opening file" << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    unsigned long long fileSize = fs::file_size(source);
    unsigned long numChunks = fileSize / chunkSize + (fileSize % chunkSize != 0);
    std::string outputFilename;
    char buffer[1024];
    unsigned long i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < numChunks; i++) {
        outputFilename = outputPrefix + std::to_string(i);
        std::ofstream outputFile(outputFilename, std::ios::binary);
        if (!outputFile) {
            std::cerr << "Error opening output file" << std::endl;
            inputFile.close();
            exit(1);
        }
        unsigned long bytesToWrite = chunkSize;
        while (bytesToWrite > 0) {
            unsigned long readSize = sizeof(buffer) < bytesToWrite ? sizeof(buffer) : bytesToWrite;
            inputFile.read(buffer, readSize);
            outputFile.write(buffer, readSize);
            if (!inputFile) {
                break;
            }
            bytesToWrite -= readSize;
        }
        outputFile.close();
    }
    inputFile.close();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc != 3 && argc != 4) {
        std::cerr << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " <source_file> <output_prefix> [chunk_size_in_bytes]" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    std::string sourceFile = argv[1];
    std::string outputPrefix = argv[2];
    unsigned long chunkSize = (argc == 4) ? std::strtoul(argv[3], nullptr, 10) : defaultChunkSize;
    if (chunkSize == 0) {
        std::cerr << "Invalid chunk size." << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    splitFile(sourceFile, outputPrefix, chunkSize);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't recall ever having invoked `split` without `-l line_count`. (And usually what I _really_ want is valid .csv or .txt lines totaling no more than byte_count in length.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm repeatedly surprised by the basic tools that Windows users somehow manage without.  This is a worthwhile objective.

---

> ```
> #include <iostream>
> #include <fstream>
> #include <string>
> #include <vector>
> #include <filesystem>
> ```

That's very nearly sorted; it's useful to have standard includes in order, as it makes it easy to check whether the one you need is already present.

---

> ```
> #define defaultChunkSize 500'000'000UL;
> ```

I'd write that as

```
static constexpr auto defaultChunkSize = 500'000'000UL;
```

No need to get the preprocessor involved here.

---

> ```
>     std::cerr << "Error opening file" << std::endl;
>     exit(1);
> ```

No need to flush `std::err` here, since exiting will do that for us.  We might be able to provide more information by using `std:perror()` (from `<cstdio>`) instead.

`std::exit` is misspelt, and it's not defined, as we failed to include `<cstdlib>`.  It's not the best error-handling technique, as it will not call destructors of in-scope objects.

---

> ```
>     if (!outputFile) {
>         std::cerr << "Error opening output file" << std::endl;
>         inputFile.close();
> ```

That `close()` would be unnecessary if we simply returned an appropriate failure indication (or exception) rather than calling `std::exit()`.

---

> ```
>  char buffer[1024];
> ```

That's a very small buffer size for copying file contents.  Consider something much larger.

---

> ```
>         inputFile.read(buffer, readSize);
>         outputFile.write(buffer, readSize);
>         if (!inputFile) {
>             break;
>         }
> ```

We need to check that the `read()` was successful *before* writing the buffer contents.  If it fails having performed a partial read, we'll need to write `inputFile.gcount()` characters rather than `readSize`.

We're completely missing any check that the write was successful.  It can fail for many reasons, the most obvious being reaching one of the size limits (quota, filesystem or process limit).

---

> ```
>     outputFile.close();
> ```

Discarding the return value of `close()` means that we don't know whether the file was successfully written.  That's a Bad Thing, as it means that the program could fail to perform its task without any error message.

---

It shouldn't be necessary to measure the input file or to compute `numChunks` in advance.  In any case, the information could be out of date by the time we use it.  Instead, just keep reading from the input file until we reach EOF (or get an error), and start a new file whenever we have written the chunk size to the current one.

---

> ```
>     std::cerr << "Invalid chunk size." << std::endl;
>     return 1;
> ```

Consider using the `EXIT_FAILURE` and `EXIT_SUCCESS` macros from `<cstdlib>` for clearer return values from `main()`.